# python help usage issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am not sure exactly how to make use of python help.

eg. I need to know about the QLineEdit.EchoMode(), I need to know how to use this function, input and output.

I typed :

> > > help(QLineEdit.EchoMode)

I get a long list of things but nothing gives me what I want,i.e.; the arguments it will take or the value that it will return.

Please suggest how to use it.
Thanks!

its something this-

```
Help on class EchoMode in module PyQt4.QtGui:

class EchoMode(__builtin__.int)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      EchoMode
 |      __builtin__.int
 |      __builtin__.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __reduce__ = _pickle_enum(...)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from __builtin__.int:
 |  
 |  __abs__(...)
 |      x.__abs__() <==> abs(x)
 |  
 |  __add__(...)
 |      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
 |  
 |  __and__(...)
```

Comment: Could you post what it spits out?

Comment: @Al.Sal It is really long.

Comment: OP: Here is the online documentation that may help: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum

Comment: @Al.Sal please don't encourage use of off-site code pasting.

Comment: See also: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#echoMode-prop

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, you're right. I'll delete that comment - I was just thinking it would be helpful to explain the output of `help`. Then again, I forgot the scrollbar text boxes... hehe. I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since pyqt is simply wrapping C++ code, don't expect the docstrings to be very useful. You can quickly access the C++ class descriptions, or their pyqt analogue by a google search or download the whole qt documentation set. These pages commonly group the attributes, methods, signals, slots and events for any class, along with all inherited ones.

Also, the examples included in most pyqt distributions are very helpful. However, you can often tell what a qt method needs in terms of parameters by the signature and, because the whole library is fairly consistently coded, a small amount of experience goes a long way.

In this case: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the `help()` just reads the `.__doc__` along with the attributes and methods, if applicable. So, if the developer didn't fill it out completely `help()` won't help. I generally mix `dir()` and `help()` until I get to the method or class I need, and if it doesn't yield what I'm looking for I google it.

EDIT: I removed the google link as that's been posted already and just left the explanation of how `help()` works. Basically, without well written doc strings, `help()` isn't that useful.

Comment: The question is not about QLineEdit.EchoMode....it is only about using help() in python....I am googling almost everything just because there is no proper documentation in the help...anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: @user3342969 Python isn't magic - for many libraries, the documentation and `help ` output are generated from the same sources.